# Why this statement is false?

Tags: statistics

I know that variance is the square of the standard deviation.

I must to answer if is true or false this statement:

> If the variance is equal to standard deviation, then they are just both
>   equal to 1.

I answered true, because if standard deviation is $1$ , its square is $1^2$, that is the same.

But the correct answer was **false**, so I would like to know why it is false

Comment: $x^2=x$ has two solutions. $x=1$ and $x=0$.

Comment: ... and $x=\infty$, which given the context might be relevant.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle I'm not sure because statistics is not my strong suit, but ain't we can ignore the $\infty$ solution for standard deviation?

Comment: @Holo Statistics makes me want to throw up, and for the record it is not math. But variance is just an integral and in integration theory the ends of the real line are commonly used. So, infinite variance could potentially be a case in which people might consider that equation being satisfied.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle  I 1000‰ agree on the first part. And thanks for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've fallen into the pit of concluding that $P \implies Q$ is the same as $Q \implies P$. The converse is **not** equivalent to the original statement.

Yes, it's true that if the variance is $1$ then the standard deviation equals the variance.

No, it's not true that variance being equal to standard deviation implies that the variance is $1$; after all, as pointed out in the comments, $x^2 = x$ has two solutions.

Comment: Yes, there may be more solutions, if you raise it algebraically like: $ x ^ 2 = x $, but in the statement it says that they will be equal to 1, therefore we are only talking about $ 1 ^ 2 = 1 $(that it's correct). That's why I still do not understand

Comment: The statement is "**If** variance = standard deviation, **then** they both equal $1$." That is false, because they could both equal zero.

Comment: That made me clearer than everything, thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In logic terms, you are confusing a statement with its converse.

It's true that "If $x = 1$, then $x^{2} = x$".

But it's false that "If $x^{2} = x$, then $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The true version of that statement is:

> If the variance is equal to the standard deviation $(\sigma^2 = \sigma)$, then they are both equal to one, or both equal to zero, or both infinite.